# Adding a condition to fieldlabel extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a TextField created that i gave a fieldlabel... Now i'm trying to add an if/else condition to the fieldlabel so that if condition is true, fieldlabel A appears else B appears. Any idea on how to do so, and if it's possible?

```
Number = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField', {
        id : 'LeaseNumber',
        padding: '40 5 5 5',
        fieldLabel: '<span style="font-size: 13px">Number</span>',
        width :'42%'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example of a condition that is executed at time of creation of the component:

```
width: Ext.theme.is.Triton?100:80,
```

If you want the fieldLabel to change dynamically whenever another checkbox is changed, you would have to do as follows:

```
    xtype:'checkbox',
    listeners:{
        change:function(box, newValue) {
            box.nextSibling().setFieldLabel(newValue?'Width':'Height');
        }
    }
},{
    xtype:'textfield',
```